# Encoding a line break in a string without using HTML

Tags: javascript, string, dojo, line-breaks, gfx

Is there a way to encode a line break into a string without using any HTML entities or tags?
Specifically, I would like a string that I pass into the dojox.gfx renderer to display a line break.

Comment: usually \n is the charachter representing a line break, but I don't know dojox.gfx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape it with `\n` or `\u000A`, see:

[How do I break a string across more than one line of code in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/)