# javascript breaks when spaces are set within it

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I break a string across more than one line of code in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript)

Hi i am new to javascript and i struggling to get this to work.

Basically everything works fine, but as soon as there are any spaces within it, it breaks.

Its pulling from the database a text string, which is fine until there is a space like as follows:

```
var getHtml = '<div class="counterwrap"><div class="countertitle"><h1><?php echo $ublunderconstructioninfo->title ; ?></h1></div><div class="counter"><div class="counternumbers"><div id="counterdays"></div><p>Days</p></div><div class="counternumbers"><div id="counterhours"></div><p>Hours</p></div><div class="counternumbers"><div id="counterminutes"></div><p>Minutes</p></div><div class="counternumberslast"><div id="counterseconds"></div><p>Seconds</p></div></div><div class="countertext">this is where some text goes</div></div>';
            $("body").html(getHtml);
```

Now if there is a space like this, then then it breaks:

```
    var getHtml = '<div class="counterwrap"><div class="countertitle"><h1><?php echo $ublunderconstructioninfo->title ; ?></h1></div><div class="counter"><div class="counternumbers"><div id="counterdays"></div><p>Days</p></div><div class="counternumbers"><div id="counterhours"></div><p>Hours</p></div><div class="counternumbers"><div id="counterminutes"></div><p>Minutes</p></div><div class="counternumberslast"><div id="counterseconds"></div><p>Seconds</p></div></div><div class="countertext">this is where some text goes

but when there is a linebreak

like this it breaks
</div></div>';
            $("body").html(getHtml);
```

Comment: Look here: [How to create multiline strings][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/how-to-create-multiline-strings

Comment: Put the backslash at the end of the line

Comment: You all didn't understand his question! It is not a duplicate! The answer to your problem is: Use PHP and replace all "\n" in that string. You probably want to replace them with "<br />" so the spaces will be shown on the page.

Comment: @DisplayName thank you for your answer, it was the correct answer as it now works now i have replaces the \r\n with a <br />

Answer (score 1):

This is because strings in javascript can't be split across multiple lines.

Instead do something like:

```
var SomeString = "line 1\n" + 
   "line 2\n" + 
   "line 3";
```

Or

```
var SomeString = "line 1\
    line 2\
    line 3";
```

Comment: how can i setup a var like you have said from a dynamic vairable called from the database. For instance i am calling the text which you can see from <?php echo stringfromdatabase ; ?>

Comment: @RobertGouveia, normally I'd recommend asking this as a separate question, however I'm certain it's already been asked. If you're not satisfied by the answers provided, the correct next step is to open a bounty as per the [faq].

Comment: @zzzzBov i do not have a lot of rep as i am new, i didnt even know about this website until today when trying to search for my question.

Comment: @RobertGouveia, then welcome to [SO]. I recommend thoroughly reviewing the [faq] thoroughly in addition to [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: -1 Because it does not answer the actual question.