# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL when putting html in var

Tags: javascript

I am just putting some html in a var and I get this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
typeForm = "Type de RDV : <br />                                                                                                                                                                                   
            <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='0' class='rdv-type' />Client seul<br />                                                                                                                     
            <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='1' class='rdv-type' />Client + con<br />                                                                                                           
            <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='2' class='rdv-type' />Visite agence<br />                                                                                                                   
            <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='4' class='rdv-type' />Signature PV<br />                                                                                                                    
            <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='5' class='rdv-type' />Con step<br />                                                                                                           
            <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='3' class='rdv-type' />Land analysis<br />";
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong. I get a warning around first `<br />`.

I checked other posts but I really dont see why it does this.

Comment: Have you tried removing parts of the string to identify which part is causing the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I break a string across more than one line of code in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript)

Comment: @Quentin If you don't know that it's a problem with the broken string and only have the error-message you will never be able to get to that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because in JavaScript you can't simply start the new line in a string value, you should either *'escape the new line'*:

```
var smth = "Some text \
            continues here \
            and here";
```

or use string concatenation:

```
var smth = "Some text " +
           "continues here " +
           "and here";
```

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. I had no idea about that. I am kina new to jQuery/js and you sir have taught me something I could have never figured out alone.

Answer (score 1):

```
typeForm = "Type de RDV : <br/>" +                                                                                                                                                                                   
        "<input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='0' class='rdv-type' />Client seul<br />" +                   
....
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

When line breaking append a "+" before each new line

Comment: Thanks. I used VisioN solution with the \ but this work great as well thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your html string is not correctly formed, Concatenate all line to make a string comprising many lines.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bec4H/)**

```
typeForm = "Type de RDV : <br /> " +                                                                                                                                                                                  
           " <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='0' class='rdv-type' />Client seul<br />      " +                                                                                                               
           " <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='1' class='rdv-type' />Client + con<br />      " +                                                                                                     
          "  <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='2' class='rdv-type' />Visite agence<br />       " +                                                                                                            
           " <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='4' class='rdv-type' />Signature PV<br />         " +                                                                                                           
            "<input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='5' class='rdv-type' />Con step<br />           " +                                                                                                
    " <input type='radio' name='rdv-type' value='3' class='rdv-type' />Land analysis<br />";

    alert(typeForm );
```