# JS variable encoded with json_encode returns SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, json

Previously, I am encountering "unterminated string literal strange error" in JS: [SyntaxError: unterminated string literal strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170153/syntaxerror-unterminated-string-literal-strange-error)

I kinda fix it using json_encode since newlines are escaped.

Now I am getting these odd results, for example this JS variable (processed with json_encode):

```
        cacheObj_open.handler='<pre class="brush: html;">"&lt;html&gt;\r\n&lt;body&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;Hello world.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n&lt;\/body&gt;\r\n&lt;\/html&gt;"</pre>';
```

Will output with codes having double quotes around them:

```
"<html>
<body>
<p>Hello world.</p>
</body>
</html>"
```

The above code runs without console error. But the one below (also processed with json_encode) throws *SyntaxError: missing ; before statement* error:

```
cacheObj_open.handler='<pre class="brush: html;">"\r\n&lt;?php\r\n$stmt = $dbh-&gt;prepare(&quot;SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?&quot;);\r\nif ($stmt-&gt;execute(array($_GET['name']))) {\r\n  while ($row = $stmt-&gt;fetch()) {\r\n    print_r($row);\r\n  }\r\n}\r\n?&gt;"</pre>';
```

What is the best way to avoid any errors when outputting HTML entity source code to a JS variable? I know that json_encode will escape some new lines(this is a good idea) but based on the above example, it still throws an error for some codes. I appreciate any inputs and suggestions.

I have tried adding addslashes on PHP side but it still throws the error.

Comment: How are you generating the `cacheObj_open.handler = ...` line?

Comment: You can see the complete javascript here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170153/syntaxerror-unterminated-string-literal-strange-error

Comment: That doesn't show how you actually put the encoded string into HTML. The right approach is using `cacheObj_open.handler = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;` , and NOT putting any quotes around the output of `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in this case is at `execute(array($_GET['name']`, the single quotes here close the quotes surrounding the whole string. They should be escaped with a backslash.