# issue with jquery .append function

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

i am trying to append some html content to a div.

here is my jquery script

```
jQuery( "#navigation" ).append('<li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>');
```

but this not working. showing some  error. please help me. Thanks

Comment: What error do you get? please provide working code

Comment: see if your code is absolutely inlined then there should not be any error.

Comment: error in firefox : SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
 

$( "#navigation" ).append( "<li><a class='nop' href='#'><i class='social fa fa-2...

Comment: It's never good to just write _showing some error_. If you want to get an answer and won't get downvoted for a low quality question you should always provide **all** relevant information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: unterminated string literal strange error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170153/syntaxerror-unterminated-string-literal-strange-error)

Comment: See also this question [How do I break a string across more than one line of code in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the last `});`

```js
jQuery( "#navigation" ).append('<li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i>test</a></li><li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i>test</a></li><li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-google-plus"></i>test</a></li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation"></div>
```

Comment: sorry, that typo error. quetion edited. removed });   still error :(

Answer (score 0):

remove this:

```
});
```

You don't need the `});` brace there.

#### Update:

As question has updated, then you can try the below one.

you can create your list items by concatenation this way:

```
jQuery(function(){
   var lists = '<li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a></li>'+
               '<li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></a></li>' +
               '<li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>';

   jQuery("#navigation").append(lists);
}); // doc ready closed
```

Comment: please check. question edited

Comment: you can check the updated one and make sure if your page has loaded the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, you have some '});' without need.

```
$( "#navigation" ).append('<li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a></li><li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></a></li><li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qbvw1a93/3/

Comment: please check. question edited

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
$("#navigation").html($('#navigation').html() + '<li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a></li><li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></a></li><li><a class="nop" href="#"><i class="social fa fa-2x fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>');
```

Although your problem relies on the ILLEGAL line break inside the strings, something you can't do inside javascript.