# I am getting un-terminated string literal for my userextension.js file in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I've the following code to add in userextensions.js file whenever I add the following piece of code it gives me following error

Failed to load user-extensions.js: Syntax Error: Unterminated String Literal

```
 Selenium.prototype.doInsertCKEditor = function(locator,word) 
    { 
        this.doWaitForCondition("var x = 
    Selenium.browserbot.findElementOrNull('//td[@id=\"cke_contents_form 
    \"]');x != null;", "50000"); 
        this.doRunScript("CKEDITOR.instances['"+locator+"'].setData('"+word 
    +"');");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170153/syntaxerror-unterminated-string-literal-strange-error

Comment: Missing a } aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

the best way to remove this ever I found it to open your script in some javascript editor I did it in Adobe Dreamweaver and it pin pointed the line where actually the problem is and I resolved this