# javascript Syntax error : Unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I break a string across more than one line of code in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript)

I am getting an unterminated string literal error. Please see my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function embedVideo(url){
alert(video);
var video= '
<OBJECT ID="player" width="800" height="450" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
<PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="">
<PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="false">
<PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
<PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
<param name="uiMode" value="full" />
<PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True" />
<EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" width="800" height="450" SRC="" NAME="MediaPlayer"
ShowControls="1" displaysize="4" ShowStatusBar="1" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0"> </EMBED></OBJECT>
';
alert(video);
jQuery("#videoScreen").html(video);
return true;
}
</script>
```

Please help...

Answer (score 12):

Javascript doesn't support multi-line strings, you'll need to either:

- make that tag one big line, or
- use a trailing backslash on each line to indicate "continuation", or
- use multiple strings joined together.

Answer (score 2):

I have copied and pasted the code into my machine.
And I found the error.

On line 4,

```
var video= '
<OBJECT ID="player" width="800" height="450" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
```

This is causing the error.
You have put a line break on line 4 after the equal to `=` sign.
Javascript considers every line break as new statement.
Please remove unnecessary line breaks and it should work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign multiline values to a variable in js, so you have to write it this way:

```
var video = '<OBJECT ...>';
video += '...';
```

But... the way you're creating an `object` element is not correct - you'd better use `document.createElement` for more clear code.