# "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" error when embedding php variable in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, embed

It's a simple embed and I don't understand why it's getting this error.

In the action class...

```
$TESTME = "what";
```

In the view....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var someVale = "<?php echo $TESTME; ?>";
        alert(someVale);
    });
</script>
```

The error is pointing to right after the var assignment first quote

ie. var someVale = "< br />....

Comment: if `$TESTME` has `"` things will crash and burn :)

Comment: That looks like a php error message, I'm thinking undefined variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript Syntax error : Unterminated string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256320/javascript-syntax-error-unterminated-string-literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, you can get away with echo-ing variables, but sometimes those echoed strings contain line terminators, or quotes (aka string delimiters). You can test, and test again, but you just *have* to defend yourself against "malicious" and "unpredictable" input. In this very answer I've used both single and double quotes
You can `str_replace` or `urlencode` your strings, which would solve your problems, but honestly... what on earth is wrong with `json_encode`? It's just perfect for Server <-> client data, like you're using:

```
var someVal = JSON.parse(<?= json_encode(array('data' => $someVar));?>).data;
```

All chars that need escaping will be escaped... job done, and with a "native" PHP function.

*Update:*
As the comments below show, this is probably a PHP error, due to a scope issue. Instead of declaring a variable in the class, you should declare a property:

```
class Foo
{
    public $theProperty = null;
    public function __construct($argument = null)
    {
        $this->theProperty = $argument;//assign a variable, passed to a method to a property
        $someVar = 123;//this variable, along with $argument is GC'ed when this method returns
    }
}
//end of class
$instance = new Foo('Value of property');
echo $instance->theProperty;//echoes "value of property"
$anotherInstance = new Foo();//use default value
if ($anotherInstance->theProperty === null)
{//is true
    echo 'the property is null, default value';
    $anotherInstance->theProperty = 'Change a property';
}
```

This is, basically how it works. I don't know how you're using your view-script, so the code below might not work in your case (It's what you can do in Zend Framework, in the controller):

```
public function someAction()
{
    $instance = new Foo('Foobar');
    $this->view->passedInstance = $instance;//pass the instance to the view
}
```

Then, in your viewscript, you'd do something like this:

```
var someVal = JSON.parse('<?= json_encode(array('data' => $this->passedInstance->someProperty)); ?>').data;
```

But in order for my answer to work in your case, I'd have to see how you're rendering the view... are you using a framework? Are you using the classic MVC pattern, or is the view-script just something you `include`?

Comment: @James show the entire script tag(the generated code) where you get the error. It looks to me as you get a php error, which then causes the js error.

Comment: @James: ?? What do you mean? You wrote the PHP code yourself, right? Also, I've just read your question again... am I right in saying you're echo-ing a PHP variable in a view-script, that was declared in a class? In that case: You're out of scope/luck... classes are _"self-contained"_, you can only access public properties, not the variables.

Comment: Soo.  I think you're right and it's a scope problem.  How do I get that php variable into the view?!?!

Comment: pass the instance of that class to the view, assign the variable as a property, and access it like that... I'll update my answer

Comment: problem solved.  I am new with symfony and I had to have $this->TESTME. Thanks!

Comment: @james: nips, I wish you'd told me you were using symphony... anyway, I have updated my answer to reflect the scope issue... without being a rep whore: you might want to accept a couple of answers

Answer (score 4):

You need to examine the content of `$TESTME`. It either contains newline characters or double quotes. The error you're seeing usually indicates that the string in question is broken over several lines, or that the number of quotes don't match up.

In your case, it's probably newlines...

```
var someVale = "< br />
<tag>
<tag>
<tag>";
```

This obviously won't work, and you need to deal with the string so that you end up with...

```
var someVale = "< br />\n<tag>\n<tag>\n<tag>";
```

You can convert your PHP variable with something like...

```
$TESTME = str_replace(chr(13), "\n", $TESTME);
```

(Depending on the OS involved, your newlines may also be `chr(13) . chr(10)`.)

Comment: I define $TESTME right there.  it only consists of "what".  Where could it become corrupted?  I also tried making it a number. Same error

Comment: Nice catch on the newline. He should also do a `nl2br()`.

Comment: It'd probably be a good idea to just use a JSON encoding facility.

Comment: nl2br() did not work
json_encode  did not work
str_replace technique did not work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You still need to visually inspect the contents of `$TESTME`. If you post the actual content here, we can provide better assistance. Even so, it'll give you a better idea of what the issue may be. You should also look for errant `"`s in the string. Try modifying your code to `var someVale = '<?php echo $TESTME; ?>';`.

Comment: Tried that.  How do I visually inspect the contents of $TESTME, and where?

Comment: You can `echo` it to the page as a start, but the preferred method is to set up error logging and use `error_log` to send it there. [PHP - error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)