# How should I format jQuery for multiple lines of html insertion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error, unless I put all the html on one line, which I don't want to do.

```
$(this).closest('tr').after(
    '<tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>'
);
```

Comment: Check this question to see how to break a string in several lines without concatenation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('tr').after(
    '<tr> \
        <td></td> \
        <td></td> \
        <td></td> \
        <td></td> \
        <td></td> \
        <td></td> \
        <td></td> \
        <td></td> \
    </tr>'
);
```