# Illegal error when trying to append

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is, I'm attempting to append something I saw in a tutorial for making rainbow text to head, as I'm trying add it to the custom color codes in a nodejs based chat. I'm getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" message in console. Can someone tell me what my errors are or possibly fix it for me? Thanks in advance.

```
$('head').append('<style> #chat .rainbow { background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear,     left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f),  color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9,  #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) )!important;
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6,  #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
  color:transparent!important;
  -webkit-background-clip: text!important;
  background-clip: text!important; } </style>')
```

Comment: is this code in one line, or do you use line breaks?

Comment: Your string argument to append is split up.

Comment: you need to watch for linebreaks in strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered, it works now. I've haven't used append before and was trying to just directly copy paste the CSS. The line breaks worked.

Comment: The `"</"` character sequence must be escaped inside a `<script>` element. See: <[http://stackoverflow.com/a/236106/3478852](http://stackoverflow.com/a/236106/3478852)>.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('head').append('<style> #chat .rainbow { background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear,     left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f),  color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9,  #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) )!important; \
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6,  #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) ); \
  color:transparent!important; \
  -webkit-background-clip: text!important; \
  background-clip: text!important; } </style>');
```

Adding a backslash at the end of each line tells the JavaScript engine that the string will continue to the next line, thus avoiding the automatic semicolon insertion annoyance.

Comment: Why should the OP try that?

Comment: @FelixKling Explanation added. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it all in one line.

```
$('head').append('<style> #chat .rainbow { background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9,  #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) )!important; background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6,  #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );color:transparent!important;-webkit-background-clip: text!important; background-clip: text!important; } </style>');
```

I'm afraid you can't just start new lines in JavaScript.

Comment: Why should the OP try that?

Answer (score 0):

With multiple strings:

```
$('head').append('<style> #chat .rainbow { background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear,     left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f),  color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9,  #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) )!important;' +
'background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6,  #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );' +
'color:transparent!important;' +
'-webkit-background-clip: text!important;' +
'background-clip: text!important; } </style>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it on one line as javascript String literals can't span multiple lines by default. This can be resolved by adding `\` at the end, or concatinating the String (or just doing multiple appends, but that makes less sense in this scenario as it's a whole style tag that's being added).