# Format code inside jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, append

just wondering if its possible to format code whilst using the append() function.

Im creating a form with JSON and jQuery but this form will be quite large and Its going to be annoying to work on one long line of code... so instead of:

```
$('<div id="admin-overlay-login"></div><form class="editUserDetails-form" action="admin/process/saveUserDetails.php">Editing Details for User:'+response.username+' , User ID:'+response.userID+'</form>').appendTo('body');
```

Is it possible to somehow do similiar to:

```
$('<div id="admin-overlay-login"></div>
  <form class="editUserDetails-form" action="admin/process/saveUserDetails.php">
    Editing Details for User:'+response.username+' , User ID:'+response.userID+'
  </form>').appendTo('body');
```

I know the above will break the code and wont work. But surely theres a way to do what im asking? Unless HOW im doing it is correct / frowned upon :)

Craig.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for that! Didn't think about asking for breaking lines. Craig.

Answer (score 0):

You can say like bellow

```
$('<div id="admin-overlay-login"></div>\
  <form class="editUserDetails-form" action="admin/process/saveUserDetails.php">\
    Editing Details for User:'+response.username+' , User ID:'+response.userID+'\
  </form>').appendTo('body');
```