# How to show a result of var_export() in a div container?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm  trying to show a result of var_export() in a separate div container.

```
$value = var_export($myarray,true);
echo "<script>$('#div_debug').html('$value');</script>";
```

and i get the this error:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

can anyone help me?

With ordinary Strings the Code is Working fine, but not with th eresult of of Var_dump/var_export

Comment: As the result of a var_export may contain quotes, you have to escape them before injecting it into your js

Comment: echo "<script>$('#div_debug').html('.$value.');</script>";

Comment: This might help explain why you're getting that specific error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = var_export($myarray,true);
echo '<div id="#div_debug">'.$value.'</div>';
```

or:

```
$value = var_export($myarray,true);
echo "<script>$('#div_debug').html('.$value.');</script>";
```

Comment: the first way is working, but i want to change content of the div dynamically as the second way. I get the same error

Comment: ok with this one: echo "<script>$('#div_debug').html(".$value.");</script>"; (check the double quotes)

Comment: i'm sorry but this one tries to run the content of $value i get: SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)