# How to make vscode compact multiple lines to a single line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have 4 lines like this in vscode:

> 1 line;
> 2 line;
> 3 line;
> 4 line;

Does vscode have a shortcut that can quickly compact 4 lines to 1 line like this:

> 1 line;   2 line;  3 line;   4 line;

Answer (score 445, accepted):

Select your code =>
<kbd>F1</kbd> => "Join Lines"

You can also create a keyboard shortcut for this command `editor.action.joinLines`

Default shortcut on Mac is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: The default keyboard shortcut is ctrl + J on mac.

Comment: I love VS Code! That's one of the reasons!

Comment: On linux/windows, **press** `F1`, **type** `join lines`, **click** `:gear-icon`, **press & hold ctrl** *and* **press and release sequence:** `K` + `K`.  In the new window I recommend setting the keybinding to **press & hold ctrl** *and* **press and release sequence:** `J` + `L`.  *(`ctrl + j`, `shift+ctrl+j`, `ctrl + l` are all already set)*. Chorded keybinds do not require that you let go of `ctrl` between the two combinations - but you can; it makes no difference.

Comment: What is the opposite of join lines. Split lines?

Comment: The default shortcut Ctrl+J works on windows as well.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `Ctrl`+`J` on Windows is Toggle Panel. Unless you installed a keymaps extension like Sublime keymap.

Comment: There is no keybinding for the `Join Lines` by default in VS Code windows. However, you could set it by clicking the gear icon on the right of the `Join Lines` option when you hit `F1` key

Comment: @ShivanshJagga There is no such feature because VS Code has no way of knowing where to split the line: between words? Between sentences? Something else?

Comment: On Windows, `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` brings up the Command Palette, same as `F1`.

Comment: You saved 30 minutes !!

Comment: `CTRL` - `Alt` - `j` is not bound and it's easy to remember.

Answer (score 23):

It seems vscode's "Join Lines" keyboard shortcut in macOS is `ctrl + j`:
[image]

Comment: But once I save the code, again it goes back to multiple line mode. Is there any setting I need to do with extension installed ?

Comment: also increase print width from 80 to 125(in setting), then it will keep ur code in one line

Answer (score 2):

I also had same issue and solved it.
If you use Prettier, try it as below.

```
Settings -> Prettier.printWidth"
```

The default value is 80. If you change this value higher than 80.

Comment: not working with tsx files. I set prettier formatted for tsx files but even then it is not working.

Comment: increase width in user as well in workspace setting both

Comment: It is not supported by prettier. 
https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#%EF%B8%8F-a-note-on-formatting-reversibility

Comment: Thank you! It works on .tsx files! By the way, Jaskaran Singh,
I changed "Prettier: Print Width" to 150. It works well for me. I'm very happy.

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows**

Just Install Sublime Keymapper extension in vscode.
Select Lines you want to be on single line then press`ctrl + j`

Answer (score 2):

1.select the all lines
2. press f1
3. then pop up search will open
4. search join lines
5. press enter

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Alex answer; a better option would be to bind a shortcut key to Join Lines i.e. Ctrl + Shift + u

1. Open Shortcut keys by either pressing (Ctrl + K Ctrl + S) or through GUI by pressing the gear icon on the lower left bottom.
2. Then search for Join Lines in the top search text input
3. double-clicking keybinding and pressing Ctrl + Shift + u

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use these two in vs code.

Fold multiple lines: `ctrl + shift + [`
Unfold multiple lines: `ctrl + shift + ]`

I prefer these because I want to use prettier as well.

Comment: That *folds* lines. It does not *join* them.