# how to give a line break with the javascript string without breaking javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to add a break in the javascript with the below situation.

```
<?php
$str_alert = "";
if(isset($case1)){
    $str_alert .= "have case1 \n";
}
if(isset($case2)){
    $str_alert .= "have case2 \n";
}
if(isset($case3)){
    $str_alert .= "have case3 \n";
}
if(!empty($str_alert)){
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert("<?=$str_alert?>");
});
</script>
```

it break the javascript code and shows the error

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

please give me any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\` to escape `\n` in php. Try following code

```
<?php
$str_alert = "";
if(isset($case1)){
    $str_alert .= "have case1 \\n";
}
if(isset($case2)){
    $str_alert .= "have case2 \\n";
}
if(isset($case3)){
    $str_alert .= "have case3 \\n";
}
if(!empty($str_alert)){
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert("<?=$str_alert?>");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to represent characters that are not allowed as literals in JS strings (like new lines) by escape characters.

Since JSON is a data format based on a subject of JavaScript's literal syntax, you can use PHP's `json_encode` function to convert any basic data type (string, number, array, associative array) into JavaScript code with all the correct escape characters.

By default it will even escape `/` so you can safely output the string `</script>`.

```
alert(<?=json_encode($str_alert);?>);
```

Since the `"` will be included in the JSON, you should not add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript strings can't break across newlines without an escape (). See this question for detailed answers:

[How do I break a string across more than one line of code in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508269/how-do-i-break-a-string-across-more-than-one-line-of-code-in-javascript)